# RTL-SDR data types

Tags: software-defined-radio

I am using [pyrtlsdr](https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr) to read samples from an RTL-SDR.  As in the example on the page, I am getting samples with `sdr.read_samples(x)`.

The RTL-SDR returns 16 bits per sample: 8 bits for I, 8 bits for Q.  The result of the `read_samples` function is a numpy array of type complex128 ("Complex number, represented by two 64-bit floats (real and imaginary components)").  This results in readings like `(-0.0196078431373+0.00392156862745j)`.

What am I missing?

Comment: This question seems to have been asked in the correct place already: https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr/issues/80

Comment: This software normalizes the samples to be withing the range [-1,1]. Have you examined multiple samples to verify that you only get 256 distinct values?

Comment: @MBaz - why 128 bit complex type, though?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess would be that the software normalizes the samples to double-precision (64 bit) floats, and then packs them into a 128-bit complex. This is not an unusual practice.

Comment: @MBaz - thanks, make it an answer if you want, it is helpful

Comment: I'm glad it's useful, but I don't want to make it an answer because I'm just guessing.